# Using Google Cloud Messaging for Android

Tags: java, android, http, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

So my app is basically finished. Now I am starting with the "advanced" stuff: Communicating with a server and using Google Cloud Messaging. I need to send the value of a preference to the server (an integer), and the server has to return a specific push notification depending on the value. My questions are:

Where can I read more about setting up GCM in general?

How do I send the value of the preference to the server?

What language should I use to write the script for the server? (PHP?)

How much time would the whole implementation consume? (I am already experienced with java, eclipse etc. but not really with server stuff and php)

Comment: search on google you will get so many examples for GCM

Comment: check this link [Device To Device Messaging Using Google Cloud Messaging GCM](http://androidexample.com/Device_To_Device_Messaging_Using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=122&aaid=142)

Comment: The way you worded your question makes me wonder if GCM is really what you want.  If all you want to do is send something to a server and then get a response to what you send back to the same device then you are not really talking about GCM.  GCM is more for a case were you have a server running, some event on the server happens and you want to notify a specific device or set of devices,  ie the devices don't start the  communication process , they are just listening for events from your server

Comment: Well maybe I didn't explain enough. The notification is of course triggered when something happens on the server (but that is another matter... It is always triggered when a certain document is uploaded). But it is possible to send a value to the server via GCM and somehow link it to the registration id, right? EDIT: or would it be better if the server sends all different types of push notifications, and the app itself filters and displays only the needed notification depending on the preference value?

Comment: generally GCM is server to device only,  there is some beta thing that you can sign up for to go from device to server , but I think most people just use normal networking and post to the server

Comment: So, in what format is a certain message sent to the user aplication? is it only a string or is it already a complete notification? Or do I decide what is send via GCM?

Comment: yes you can send some data along with the notification, for example I send down other users gps locations  ... I will add my own answer with some more info as well

Comment: I recommend first to read official [GCM documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). There enough information to implement own gcm infrastructure. And then you can look at [my dev push server](http://1-dot-sigma-freedom-752.appspot.com/) and [its source code](https://bitbucket.org/azatsepin/gcmpusher) written on Java which you know.

Answer (score 1):

Google cloud messaging is mainly intended to send notifications from a server to one or more devices in response to some event on your server.

Here is the description from the developer page.

> Send data from your server to users' Android-powered devices
>
> This could be a lightweight message telling your app there is new data
>   to be fetched from the server (for instance, a movie uploaded by a
>   friend), or it could be a message containing up to 4kb of payload data
>   (so apps like instant messaging can consume the message directly). GCM
>   Architectural Overview.
>
> Send "send-to-sync" messages
>
> A send-to-sync (collapsible) message is often a "tickle" that tells a
>   mobile application to sync data from the server. For example, suppose
>   you have an email application. When a user receives new email on the
>   server, the server pings the mobile application with a "New mail"
>   message. This tells the application to sync to the server to pick up
>   the new email. Learn more »
>
> Send messages with payload
>
> Unlike a send-to-sync message, every "message with payload"
>   (non-collapsible message) is delivered. The payload the message
>   contains can be up to 4kb. Learn more »

I think a good starting point would be to read thru google's documentation which can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)